# How to edit datetime format on Seaborn heatmap without changing the date?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, seaborn

I am working with satellite data with which I extract velocities of points over several decades. I have a dataframe with datetime index, and my velocities in columns (each column represents 1 point). The database is widely incomplete, and the points do not necessarily have values at the same time as the others.

I plotted a heatmap with seaborn which works, but the datetime displays too much information (I only want "YYYY-MM-DD". However when I compute the line `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d') )` the dates are not correct anymore. How can I solve this issue ?
(The second plot shows how it is correctly displayed when the DateFormatter line is commented out).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

v1 = np.array([1671., 1756.,   1704., 1574., 1589.,   1772.,   1652., 1778., 1719.,
             1699.], dtype=float)
    
dv1 = np.array(['2015-01-21T00:00:00.032000000', '2015-01-29T00:00:00.016000000',
           '2014-06-11T00:00:00.544000000', '2014-12-20T00:00:00.160000000',
           '2014-12-28T00:00:00.144000000', '2015-01-05T00:00:00.192000000',
           '2014-07-29T00:00:00.512000000', '2015-03-02T00:00:00.080000256',
           '2015-07-08T00:00:00.112000000', '2015-08-25T00:00:00.272000000'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]')
    
v2 = np.array([1647., 1758., 1722.], dtype=float)
    
dv2 = np.array(['2015-08-10T00:00:00.032000000', '2015-02-18T00:00:00.016000000',
           '2014-09-19T00:00:00.544000000'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Velocity0': v1}, index=pd.to_datetime(dv1))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Velocity1': v2}, index=pd.to_datetime(dv2))

df1 = df1.append(df2)

df1 = df1.sort_index()

df1 = df1.sort_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = sns.heatmap(df1)
for item in ax.get_yticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(0)

for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
    
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d') )

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
plt.plot(df1)
```

[image: Seaborn plot with wrong dates]
[image: Same plot with correct dates but wrong format]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the mdates `DateFormatter` to work you would need to have a continuous time scale on the y-axis based on [matplotlib date units](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format). The problem is that the x and y-axis of seaborn heatmaps use ranges of integers. You can check the y-axis units by printing the tick locations:

```
print(ax.get_yticks())
# [ 0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  8.5  9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5]
```

This is why the `DateFormatter` has no effect. Instead, you can format the labels by using the [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) method with the `DatetimeIndex`:

```
import numpy as np     # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd    # v 1.1.3
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.0

v1 = np.array([1671., 1756., 1704., 1574., 1589., 1772., 1652., 1778., 1719., 1699.])
dv1 = np.array(['2015-01-21T00:00:00.032000000', '2015-01-29T00:00:00.016000000',
                '2014-06-11T00:00:00.544000000', '2014-12-20T00:00:00.160000000',
                '2014-12-28T00:00:00.144000000', '2015-01-05T00:00:00.192000000',
                '2014-07-29T00:00:00.512000000', '2015-03-02T00:00:00.080000256',
                '2015-07-08T00:00:00.112000000', '2015-08-25T00:00:00.272000000'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]')
    
v2 = np.array([1647., 1758., 1722.], dtype=float)
dv2 = np.array(['2015-08-10T00:00:00.032000000', '2015-02-18T00:00:00.016000000',
                '2014-09-19T00:00:00.544000000'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Velocity0': v1}, index=dv1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Velocity1': v2}, index=dv2)
df1 = df1.append(df2).sort_index()

ax = sns.heatmap(df1)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(6,6)
ticklabels = [df1.index[int(tick)].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for tick in ax.get_yticks()]
ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabels);
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: I tried on my code (longer dataframes but similar structure) and I got the following error: `The number of FixedLocator locations (81), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (56511)`
Note that I used the same script as you for the plotting. I do not understand where the location of the FixedLocator is embedded, and how it does not give an error in the example you gave. I just copy/pasted `ax.set_yticklabels(df1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` and changed "df1" for the name of my bigger dataframe (also organized with velocities in columns and dates in index.

Comment: @Nihilum I see that I forgot to account for the fact that seaborn does not generate a tick for each row of the heatmap by default (contrary to a pandas bar chart for example), thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected the code for the tick labels so that they match the generated ticks, it should now work for any dataframe size. Let me know if there is still any problem.

Comment: @Nihilum Regarding the FixedLocator and how it works: you could make the previous code for tick labels work by editing the tick locator implicitly with `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(df1.index.size)+0.5)`, but then the plot may take a while to be displayed due to the large number of labels which would be unreadable on a small figure. You could also use the FixedLocator explicitly as explained in the [ticker module](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) and [in this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html) on other types of tick locators.